# TIMEZONE_CHANGED intent being received every few seconds

Tags: android, android-intent, timezone, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I use a BroadcastReceiver with TIMEZONE_CHANGED action to reset alarms using AlarmManager just to make sure that the alarm runs exactly at the set time, not a few hours earlier or later, depending on the time zone change.

However in the latest log sent by the user, I saw information about intent with TIMEZONE_CHANGED action being received every few seconds with the user complaining about app being glitchy.

Here's my BroadcastReceiver's onReceive code

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Utils.log("OnTimeChange");
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED)) {
        Utils.log("TimeChange");
    } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
        Utils.log("TimeZoneChanged");
    }
    BroadcastsManager.updateBroadcastsFromAlarms(context,
            AlarmsDbAdapter.getInstance(context));
}
```

The manifest's intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
</intent-filter>
```

And part of the log (it goes like that for over an hour - full lenght of the log)

```
1. 19/4 7:41:54 - posting alarm 3 for 8:15 (in 0h)
2. 19/4 7:44:29 - OnTimeChange
3. 19/4 7:44:29 - TimeZoneChanged
4. 19/4 7:44:29 - posting alarm 3 for 8:15 (in 0h)
5. 19/4 7:44:54 - OnTimeChange
6. 19/4 7:44:54 - TimeChange
7. 19/4 7:44:54 - posting alarm 3 for 8:15 (in 0h)
```

It's a Samsung Galaxy S III (Android v 4.1.2). The strange thing is, that doesn't happen on my S III.
Could it be that the user has set "automatic timezone change by provider" option enabled on his/her device and information like that is sent every few seconds?

Has anyone expierienced it? I guess I will just add an option to check if timezone has actually changed before updating broadcasts, but it is still getting the receiver called every few seconds...

Comment: Have you tried turning on automatic time change on your SIII and see if the same thing happens?

Comment: @romo Yes - I didn't wrote it in the question, but I did check it on my S III both with this option being enabled and disabled.

Comment: This is an old question, but just to add something: I noticed this too and it seems to me it happens when the user has auto time change on + low connectivity. I guess when constantly switching from wi-fi, network and none the time gets reset every time you get a connection. As you wrote in the answer - the main delay comes from recreating date format objects and the like, so the obvious solution would be to compare the zones before doing anything.

Comment: This question is quite old at this point - does anyone know if the same behavior still occurs in modern Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I still don't know why timezone change and time set are called so often, but I was able to work out a solution, that lets me find out when reaction is actually needed.

Also I am listening only to timezone changes now.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

String oldTimezone = prefs.getString(PREF_TIMEZONE, null);
String newTimezone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

if (oldTimezone == null || TimeZone.getTimeZone(oldTimezone).getOffset(now) != TimeZone.getTimeZone(newTimezone).getOffset(now)) {
     prefs.edit().putString(PREF_TIMEZONE, newTimezone).commit();
     Logger.log("TimeZone time change");
    //update alarms
}
```

I added zone's time check, because very often I found out, that althought zones change, they do not differ in time in any way. Also some users claimed that they didn't even travel anywhere far when numerous changes in zones were detected - just regular trips to work and back.

Check limited number of unneeded operations.

Comment: Good work, I arrived at a similar solution, but persisted the offset instead of the ID. I did something similar for time updates where I ignore updates when the "auto time" setting is enabled, assuming that timezone and DST  related time changes will be accompanied by a timezone change, leaving only minor adjustments. When "auto time" is DISabled I respond to all time changes since they're likely to be quite rare and important when they do occur.

Comment: This answer seems correct... However, is not the condition wrong? When you are comparing the two offsets shouldn't it be not equal "!=" ?

Comment: @FerranNegre you are right. I had it like that for almost a year and only two users complained. And even then I didn't notice this... Thx for correcting me

Answer (score 1):

Avoid listening for:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
```

it seems they get called regularly also when time has not been set nor timezone changed. I suspect it is linked to the user using "*use network provided time zone and time*" in the phone's settings.

If you really **do** need to listen for these broadcasts you should check if time really has changed significantly or if its just a millisecond correction from the network provided time

Comment: To determine if the time "really has changed" I persist the "auto time" settings value and respond to time change events only when "auto time" is DISabled (as well as changes to the persisted settings value). @Koger's solution is good IMHO for timezone change monitoring (respond only to changes in GMT offset).

Comment: then how to aware timezone changes